# Discord.js v13 bot cannot send message

Tags: discord.js

Here is my code
I tried to run it and when i run the command nothing shows up
can someone pls help me with this

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });

const token =
  "MTAxNzgyMjQ1MjU1MTc5NDgxOA.GjO8F-.VWCMsDKV5_YdP1w6gnEME6Jucd7BN9OADesM4s";
const prefix = "lb!";
bot.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("Your bot is now online");
});

bot.on("messagecreate", (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLocaleLowerCase();

  if (command === "hello") {
    message.reply("Hi ${message.author}");
  }
});

bot.login(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

Message content is now a privileged intent. You may have to enable it for your bot in the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications). You could (or should) also use [interaction commands](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#registering-slash-commands) instead, so that you don't need that intent, as its purpose is to provide user privacy.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Syed Faizan Ali Kazmi, **Done Fix Your Code**

```js
// © Ahmed1Dev
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });

const token =
  "MTAxNzgyMjQ1MjU1MTc5NDgxOA.GjO8F-.VWCMsDKV5_YdP1w6gnEME6Jucd7BN9OADesM4s";
const prefix = "lb!";
bot.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("Your bot is now online");
});

bot.on("messagecreate", (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLocaleLowerCase();

  if (command === prefix + "hello") {
    message.reply("Hi ${message.author}");
  }
});

bot.login(token);
// © Ahmed1Dev
```

With Regards,
*Ahmed1Dev*

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite the code. Hope this will work

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });

const token = "never post your bot token online";
const prefix = "lb!";
bot.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("Your bot is now online");
});

bot.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === "hello") {
    message.reply(`Hi ${message.author}`);
  }
});

bot.login(token);
```

Also, if you didn't tick [Message Content Intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCiXi.png), then go tick it in [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)